# Is it possible to download a database from Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, sublimetext3

I'm following Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial and in Lesson 6 he opens the database using the Cloud 9 IDE. I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I can't figure out how to download the development.sqlite3 file. Is it possible to download a database file and open it Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Sublime is a text editor so you can't "download a database" from it. Are you trying to read a sqlite file?

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question, I'm new at this. I appreciate your response. Yes, I am trying to read the sqlite file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a Rails project using SQLite, the development.sqlite3 file should already be generated in the `db` directory within your project - there's no need to download it.

Opening the file itself in Sublime would probably not be very useful to you as it's going to be a huge series of unreadable characters representing the db. If you want to interface with the data within your db, here are some options:

- **rails dbconsole** - this command figures out which database you're using and drops you into whichever command line interface you would use with it. Once you're in the CLI, you can perform SQLite commands, such as getting lists of records from tables, making changes to data, etc. - [more info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole)
- **rails console** - assuming you have the proper models and database adapters configured, you can always drop into the Rails console - `rails c` - and use ActiveRecord to make some basic calls to the database. - [more info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)
- **SQLite GUIs** - there are many applications out there that provide a nice tabular user interface to interact with the data in your db. Some cross-platform examples for SQLite are:

  - SQLite Studio - http://sqlitestudio.pl/
  - SQLite Browser - http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both for helping me with my question. I'm working through the rails tutorial, but will be building my own app where I would like to interface with the data. I was hoping to find a way to drop the data into a spreadsheet of some kind. I will research the different options you suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to manually load the sqlite3 module (instructions for MacOS)

Copy the entire sqlite3 folder from

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3

to your Sublime Text 3 folder

Then copy

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload

To the same folder

finally on Sublime click View -> Show Console and then type

> import sqlite3